# Bundling in jquery validation engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validation-engine

I am using **bundling** in my mvc3 application. I can't bundle **jquery validation engine** for **portuguese** language.

In global.asax,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-pt").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-pt.js"
                   ));
```

In cshtml,

```
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-pt")
```

I am not getting the validation messages.

Comment: Did you define the bundles for other languages similar to Portuguese? If yes, are they working fine?

Comment: When i am trying with validationEngine-en.js , all are working fine.. When i am using any other language, it is not working..

Comment: Can you post the bundle you are using for validationEngine-en.js as well?

Comment: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"
                   ));

Comment: So for non-English locale you are not seeing the error messages in the corresponding locale?

Comment: Did you thru the link, especially the "Note to support jQuery validation for non-English locales" section? http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model